# Database table not created in Moto G3 device

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a DB with 5 tables, and all of them are created in all the devices I tested, but in Moto G3 device the unique one isn't created and I can't find the answer. The other 4 tables are created correctly.

In all the others devices this table is created without problems and I'm able to insert and execute querys on it.

Comment: Why the MySQL tag? And how should we tell you which part of your code is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was pretty unusual, i had to update the database version or in this dispositive this table isn't created.